# Accessing email send info and content via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api

we have the following use case / issue:

We want to place the info of every mailing that is being sent to the client in our external third party CRM. In addition to the info *that* something has been sent there shall be info about the exact email - either in form of the content (text) or in form of the whole html file. Now my question is how to access send information including email content via the Marketing Cloud API?

Comment: HI Greta, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this post would be improved if you **[edit]** it to be more *specific* and also to contain a *question*. A good `Question` post will outline very clearly the behavior you expect and the behavior you observe, and contain a clear question which can be answered succinctly. You have done a good job explaining desired behavior, but need to fix up the other two aspects to maximize your chances of getting good help on this site.

Comment: @AdrianLarson shall I delete this one?

Comment: No need to delete. Just a few minor improvements would make it into a good quality question.